# Python 3 - the state of things

Tags: python, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, a newcomer to the ROS scene here,

If this is discussed or described somewhere in depth, and I have just missed it, please let me know!

I am building a ROS programme which will contain a mixture of C++ and Python nodes. I am wondering what the best practice is regarding Python versions? I assume it makes sense to use a consistent version of Python, as in all projects, ROS or not. However, since one basic concept of ROS is that messages are published in a consistent syntax (allowing nodes of C++ and Python to communicate), I am wondering why mixing Python version should pose an issue.

I found [this question as a Github issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1208) for rospy. Dirk hints that it is possible if the code works under both python2 and python3, but I wondering if anyone has tips or references for doing this. Are things any different if using ROS2?

P.s. - `rospy` says that the best place for such questions is here  :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282254/python-3---the-state-of-things/) by [n1k31t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/33630/n1k31t4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am wondering why mixing Python version should pose an issue.

That's a good question. Unfortunately, a lot of code has not yet been ported from Python 2 to Python 3, so there's a lot of core ROS tools that still rely on Python 2. My advice here would be to try and write it in a Python 3 style, and, if you discover you need something that is Python 2 only, you can always fallback on Python 2 (or, better, help the maintainer port to Python 3).

> Are things any different if using ROS2?

Yes -- ROS2 is completely Python3 wrapped around C code.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2018-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [n1k31t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/33630/n1k31t4/) on 2018-02-14**:
@allenh1 - Thanks for your response! I"m still unclear about one thing - when you say to 'fall back onto Python 2', will that then mean using Python 2 only for the yet to be ported tools, so mixing versions itself isn't a problem?  I shall be looking forward to ROS2! :-)